# C# program won't download file testing to see if i can make a update for my program

Tags: c#

I've created a program which downloads a `*.zip*` file, the download progress is shown in a `progressBar`. The program then extracts the `*.zip*` file. This is what I have so far, update path points to here:

```
string updatepath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData) + "updatetest";

 public void downloadfile()
 {
        //client.DownloadFile("http://elfenliedtopfan5.co.uk/update/elfenlied_weapons.zip", updatepath);
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://elfenliedtopfan5.co.uk/update/elfenlied_weapons.zip"), updatepath);
        client.DownloadProgressChanged += client_DownloadProgressChanged;
}

void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
        int bytesin = int.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
        int totalbytes = int.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
        int kb1 = bytesin / 1024;
        int kb2 = totalbytes / 1024;

        label1.Text = kb1.ToString() + "KB out of " + kb2.ToString() + "KB (" +e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%)";
        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
}

public void seeiffile()
{
        // Set to folder path we must ensure exists.
        string updatepathex = updatepath;
        try
        {
            // If the directory doesn't exist, create it.
            if (!Directory.Exists(updatepathex))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(updatepathex);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
}

// if all above works then follow this 
public void exactzip()
{
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(updatepath + "elfenlied_weapons.zip"))
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry e in zip)
            {
                e.Extract(updatepath);
            }
        }
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        seeiffile();
        downloadfile();
}
```

My problem is that the file won't download, and the `progressBar` won't move either. I can't figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Have you debugged your code? What error(s) are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter for DownloadFileAsync needs to be a filename, not just the path.

```
string file = Path.Combine(updatePath, "test.zip")
client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://elfenliedtopfan5.co.uk/update/elfenlied_weapons.zip"), file);
```

Also you should use Path.Combine() on your `updatepath` variable or it will not contain a directory separator between `ProgramData` and `updatetest`.

Comment: thank you so much it works now :) really cant thank you enoth only problem i have now is it gives me a error when i try and do it twice or try to replace a file aka this error  i have updated path.combine on that now have not done it in this screenshot tho http://i.imgur.com/ShlSU88.png

Comment: The method expects ExtractExistingFileAction as the second parameter instead of a bool.

Comment: Please consider a look into your Error-Window next time, @SaitoHiraga. It is stating the exact problem in this case.